# PHPMailer not working with my email

Tags: php, phpmailer

It seems that my code is not working for some reason.
I did not use the real password here. 
It gives me server error #500.

This is my code:

```
    <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;



$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'dallas137.arvixeshared.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'ask@pocketrabbi.com';
$mail->Password = '~~~~~~';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom('ask@pocketrabbi.com', 'Questions');
$mail->addAddress('pocketrabbi@gmail.com', 'PocketRabbi');
$mail->addReplyTo('ask@pocketrabbi.com', 'Questions');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New Question';
$mail->Body    = 'Email: ' . $_POST["email"] . '/n Question: ' . $_POST["question"];

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    header( 'Location: http://www.pocketrabbi.com/thankyou.html' ) ;
}
?>
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,
Beginner

Comment: What is the full 500 error message in your logs? 500 = Internal Server Error. Could be a bunch of things happening.

Comment: You may want to check your error log and share that as well. A 500 error is just a general "An error occurred". If you're using apache it may possibly be located in /var/log/httpd/error_log depending on configuration. If you share that information we may be able to help you more. Or the error message from there may make the problem more evident to you.

Comment: FYI, in the following line: `$mail->Body = 'Email: ' . $_POST["email"] . '/n Question: ' . $_POST["question"];` you have an incorrect *new-line* `/n` when it should be `\n` and should also be wrapped in double-quotes: `$mail->Body = "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nQuestion: " . $_POST['question"'];`

Comment: I'm using a real online server, so no access to there, sorry.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what returned the 500 error, was it the web server running this script or the SMTP server you were connecting to?  As @Marcus mentioned, HTTP 500 means Internal Server Error, but SMTP 500 means Syntax Error.

Comment: We all use *real online servers* haha. Without access to logs, it won't be easy to track the issue down. Is the script above just a single, *one-off* page? As in you simply go to that page and the script is fired? Or is it part of a greater script?

Comment: "The pocketrabbi.com page isn’t working

pocketrabbi.com is currently unable to handle this request.
500" - Chrome

Comment: Html page sends this information to the php page.

Comment: Could be a dumb question, but the spaces before your opening `<?php` are those in your actual script? Or was that just from copy/pasting the code to here? That would throw a 'Headers Already Sent' error, which I believe is a 500 error.

Comment: And is the script above in the same directory as `PHPMailerAutoload.php`? Double check the path to `require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';`

Comment: Yes and yes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the error is an HTTP 500, you might want to check the function capitalization (such as line 8).  I believe that all of PHPMailer's functions start with capital letters.

Comment: From the codebase: `/**
     * Send messages using SMTP.
     * @return void
     */
    public function isSMTP()
    {
        $this->Mailer = 'smtp';
    }` Looks like it's lowercase 'i'.

Answer (score 0):

Internal server error (500) is not due to your PHP code. It means "server misconfiguration"

This is almost always due to a typo in a .htaccess file. At this point your PHP isn't even being looked at. The web server found an error when trying to find how to serve the requested page.

Comment: In IE it says:
"The website cannot display the page
  HTTP 500
Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•__The website has a programming error.__
What you can try:
  Retype the address."

Comment: Right, the webserver "Apache" has an error, not your PHP script.

Comment: So what should I do? (about .htaccess, etc. ...)

Comment: See if you have a .htaccess file, or possibly a php,ini file that was recently edited.